# Static assert that a function returns a weakly ordered type

Tags: c++, c++11

Minimal example:

```
template <typename TFunc>    
void func(TFunc f)
{
    //Do something like:
    double x{1}, y{2};
    bool z = f(x) < f(y);    //Do comparison somewhere
}
```

I would like to add a static_assert to the function that checks that f(x) returns a type where std::less computes. In other words I would like `f(x) < f(y)` to compile. I am currently doing something like this:

```
static_assert((decltype(f(0)){} < decltype(f(0)){}) == false, "Function f must return a weakly ordered type.");
```

But here I assume that the function returns a type that can be default initialized. Is there a better way to check this?

Comment: Not sure of your requirements... do you want to check that `bool z = f(x) < f(y)` is well formed?  C++20 `requires` might help. creating the traits might be more verbose pre-C++20., `auto func(TFunc f) -> decltype(f(0) < f(0), void())` might be an alternative (SFINAE)...

Comment: Yeah exactly, I want f(x) < f(y) to be defined. The template will not work if it isn't anyway, was just hoping to add a readable error message. Also I am on gcc 4.9.2, so can use C++11 and a few features of C++14.

Comment: [templated-check-for-the-existence-of-a-class-member-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/templated-check-for-the-existence-of-a-class-member-function) might help.

Comment: Hmm yeah I was wondering if SFINAE could help, but it doesn't seem obvious to me how it can improve the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More complicated piece of code, but this seems more general way to check this, in case somebody else needs this:

```
template <typename T>
class is_weakly_ordered_type
{
private:
    typedef int yes[1];
    typedef int no[2];

    template <typename S>
    static yes& test(decltype(std::declval<S>() < std::declval<S>())) {};
    
    template <typename S>
    static no& test(...) {};

public:
    static const bool value = sizeof(test<T>(nullptr)) == sizeof(yes);
};

template <typename TFunc, typename ... TArgs>
class returns_weakly_ordered_type
{
private:
    using TFuncRef = TFunc&;
    using return_type = typename std::result_of<TFuncRef(TArgs...)>::type;
public:
    static const bool value = is_weakly_ordered_type<return_type>::value;
};
```

Now you can do

```
template <typename TFunc>    
void func(TFunc f)
{
    static_assert(returns_weakly_ordered_type<decltype(func), double>::value, "Function func should return a weakly ordered type.");
    //Do something like:
    double x{1}, y{2};
    bool z = f(x) < f(y);    //Do comparison somewhere
}
```